# npm install error (fatal: bad object f18e4d058698a689943db9cb41f767efbc2c85ed)

Tags: npm

Recently I downloaded code from github and tried to install it.

However, I found errors during the process ass followed:

```
terrylai@Terrys-MacBook-Pro:~/copay$ npm install
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 f18e4d058698a689943db9cb41f767efbc2c85ed: fatal: bad object f18e4d058698a689943db9cb41f767efbc2c85ed
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 f18e4d058698a689943db9cb41f767efbc2c85ed: 
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code 128
```

The following is part of the package.json. Could anyone tell me how to solve it?

```
"dependencies": {
    "bitcore-wallet-client": "git://github.com/digibyte/bitcore-wallet-client.git#32b2f6434d1d4a77d4878d7dee9cf374086c3966",
    "express": "^4.11.2",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-gettext": "^0.2.15",
    "grunt-browserify": "^4.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "^0.13.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
```

BR,

Terry

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like the git link is wrong or pointing to something that doesn't exist. If you replace it with the version of bitcore-wallet-client that you need that should fix the problem.

For instance, I tried npm install with this in a package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "best bitcoin service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "please no npm errs",
  "dependencies": {
    "bitcore-wallet-client": "1.3.0",
    "express": "^4.11.2",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-gettext": "^0.2.15",
    "grunt-browserify": "^4.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "^0.13.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
}
```

and the install succeeded with some warnings:

```
npm install
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.

> fsevents@1.0.14 install /Users/phillipsc/code/temp/stackOverflow/node_modules/fsevents
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/phillipsc/code/temp/stackOverflow/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote
brocoin@1.0.0 /Users/phillipsc/code/temp/stackOverflow
├─┬ bitcore-wallet-client@1.3.0
│ ├── async@0.9.2
│ ├─┬ bip38@1.4.0
│ │ ├── bigi@1.4.2
```

With that said, it's hard to tell exactly what you will need without knowing what repo the posted subsection of package.json is from.